# Use 3 colors with the property linear-gradient in CSS

Tags: css

I would like to get this result in CSS below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNcHa.png)

There are 3 background colors. gray, dark gray and black. In looking on google, I have to use the property `linear-gradient` but I don't know how to get the result as in my example.

I am stuck I have for now this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.background-wrapper{
  padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-box{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}

.title{
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.text{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:white;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="background-wrapper">
        <img class="img-box" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/qjqq.png" alt="img-01">
        <div class="title">Planning & Strategy</div>
        <div class="text">a major breakthrough that we provide to our investors. and with a great marketing strategy.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="background-wrapper">
        <img class="img-box" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/zsrk.png">
        <div class="title">Planning & Strategy</div>
        <div class="text">a major breakthrough that we provide to our investors. and with a great marketing strategy.</div>
      </div>

       <div class="background-wrapper">
        <img class="img-box" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/13/gw1j.png">
        <div class="title">Planning & Strategy</div>
        <div class="text">a major breakthrough that we provide to our investors. and with a great marketing strategy.</div>
      </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: why not a background for each element? gradient is not suitable at all here

Comment: @Temani Afif: You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some specific class for each .background-wrapper div. Or can do like this:

```
.background-wrapper:nth-child(1) {background-color: #5a5a5a;}
.background-wrapper:nth-child(2) {background-color: #4a4a4a;}
.background-wrapper:nth-child(3) {background-color: #3e3e3e;}
```

and remove

```
background-image: linear-gradient(grey, black);
```